# How to export PATH to "sam build" command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pycharm, aws-sam-cli, aws-toolkit

I'm developing AWS Lambda function on PyCharm.
When I do "Run" button, Following error message.

```
/usr/local/bin/sam build MyFunction --template /Users/miyashiiii/Works/myapp/myapp/template.yaml --build-dir /Users/miyashiiii/Works/myapp/myapp/.aws-sam/build
Building codeuri: myapp/ runtime: python3.7 metadata: {} functions: ['MyFunction']

Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:Validation - Binary validation failed for python, searched for python in following locations  : ['/usr/bin/python'] which did not satisfy constraints for runtime: python3.7. Do you have python for runtime: python3.7 on your PATH?
```

python3.7 is on my PATH, and other some locations is on my PATH, but locations list includes only '/usr/bin/python'.

And when I do same command (/usr/local/bin/sam build ~~) on terminal, It succeed.

How to export PATH to "sam build" command?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I solved the problem for python3.8 (same for python3.7 I suppose) by linking executable into /usr/local/bin

```
ln -sf /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/
```

[EDIT Nov2021] it's `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3` nowadays [/EDIT]

To find your python directory if installed by homebrew: `brew info python@3.8`

Also, you'd probably prefer running SAM inside a docker container (option `sam build --use-container` with CLI)

In pycharm:
[image: Activate the build function inside a container]

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Note: I had to use "/usr/bin/python" as the location for WSL.

Answer (score 5):

SAM expects your version of Python do be on `PATH`, as seen [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-builders/issues/224#issuecomment-781704942)

To find your python directory if installed by homebrew: `brew info python@3.8`

In my case, this yielded `/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/libexec/bin`

Then add that to PATH with:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<Your Python version's path here>
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/libexec/bin
```

You can confirm that it has been appended by running `echo $PATH`, and you should see your new path at the end of the output.

`sam build` should then find your Python version

Answer (score 0):

Added a 3.9 environment variable and tried linking folders but didn't work for me.

The solve for me was downloading Python3.9 and then creating/selecting
a new Python Interpreter in VSCode.
This [article](https://kmahireddy123123.medium.com/python-interpreter-in-visual-studio-code-ec4433e48f4) helped me

I'm using Windows, WSL, VSCode, & Python3.10 - but needed 3.9 for SAM CLI and got the the error below

```
Error: PythonPipBuilder:Validation - Binary validation failed for python, searched for python in following locations  : ['C:\\Python310'] which did not satisfy constraints for runtime: python3.9. Do you have python for runtime: python3.9 on your PATH?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac, zshell and Python3.8 installed via homebrew, run the following command:

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

And then source your .zshrc, so changes take effect:

`source ~/.zshrc`