# Python is not configured for aws sam cli

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-sam

I am following this tutorial to build a SAM App: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html

When i did `sam build`, I got following error

```
❯ sam build
Building codeuri: hello_world/ runtime: python3.8 metadata: {} functions: ['HelloWorldFunction']

Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:Validation - Binary validation failed for python, searched for python in following locations  : ['/usr/bin/python'] which did not satisfy constraints for runtime: python3.8. Do you have python for runtime: python3.8 on your PATH?
```

I checked my python by doing this

```
❯ which python
python: aliased to python3
```

And when i do python version, i got this

```
❯ python --version
Python 3.8.2
```

So what's i am missing and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Some ideas [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/1749) to check the runtime in your template.yaml and consider re-installing awscli and sam

Comment: already verified the python version. right now uninstalling all pythons/aws-cli and sam cli

Comment: This solved the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65180787/how-to-export-path-to-sam-build-command

Comment: @EmAe If that solved your problem, please write an answer to your own question and accept it. This is allowed. See help center ["Can I answer my own question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 5):

```
python3 --version
```

solution found.
you might have selected python3.8/python3.7 as your runtime for the app. The error occurs when there is mismatching the python version of your system.
check python version:  `python3 --version` and use the same runtime of app as same as your system's python version.

Answer (score 5):

When selecting `"Use the most popular runtime and package type? [y/N]"`in the terminal, AWS SAM uses Python 3.9 runtime.
This means you need to have Python 3.9 installed on your machine.

Also note, AWS SAM CLI does not support Python 3.10. I had to downgrade to Python 3.9.11 in order for this to work.

Comment: But downgrading the system Python on a linux distro these days is suicidal.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue but after setting python 3.8 in the classpath problem resolved.