# Sam Build Failing due to python version

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, path, sam

I was running python version 2.7.18, i installed the python3 because that is runtime for the lambda to build with sam build. I keep getting this error:

"Error: PythonPipBuilder:Validation - Binary validation failed for python, searched for python in following locations  : ['/usr/bin/python', '/opt/homebrew/bin/python3', '/usr/bin/python3'] which did not satisfy constraints for runtime: python3.9. Do you have python for runtime: python3.9 on your PATH?"

I added to Path:
[image]

did not work.

I tried everything on this question and answer:
[How to export PATH to "sam build" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65180787/how-to-export-path-to-sam-build-command)

[image]
and

[image]

still getting Build failed.

when i run which python i still get:
[image]

which i check the --version for both python and python3 i get:

[image]Not sure what I am missing? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstalled both versions of python, and re-installed python3. That was the long way but it worked.